# Java If Statement

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public class If {
public static void main(String[] args) {

var myVar = "Emma";
int myInt = 1;

    if (!(myVar == myInt)) {

        System.out.println("Access granted.");

    }

}
}
```

I am learning Java now. What I should do now is to print out 'true'.

First, I tried declaring the var and int. Then I put ! operator to change 'false' into 'true'.

I thought this would work, but it doesn't. 
Why doesn't it work? Shouldn't I declare anything when I use the if statement? Thank you

Comment: `var` in Java??

Comment: `var` is not used to declare variables in Java.

Comment: var is not a type in java. So your code does not compile

Comment: javascript ? scala?

Comment: I guess myvar is a String. You have to use equals to compare

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`==` cannot be used for comparison between an `int` and a `String`. However, you can use `equals` method:

```
if (!myVar.equals(myInt)) {
    ...
}
```

This is possible because of [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Obviously, the comparison is going to fail regardless of the value of 'myVar' because the types are different. If you need to compare a string to an int reliably, first convert your string to int, and then compare with ==.

Of course, you need to declare `myVar` properly with `String` type.

Comment: `equals` with `String` and `int` will return false, even if the values are same. E.g. `String var = "5";int var1 = 5;System.out.println(var.equals(var1));`

Comment: @DarshanMehta of course, this will never return true. I assumed that's what OP wanted to achieve, though. Anyway, I added a brief explanation of what to do if he wanted to compare a string and an int.

Answer (score 2):

**the accepted answer is wrong**

Contarary to what *@dasblinkenlight*'s answer suggests, you can't compare the values of different type, even with `equals`. You first need to convert them into same type and then call `equals`, ofcourse it depends on how a class has overridden `equals()` method as well, e.g.:

```
String myVar = "1";
int myInt = 1;
System.out.println(myVar.equals(String.valueOf(myInt)));
System.out.println(myVar.equals(myInt));
```

This will print `true` and `false` with and without conversion.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't equal string to integer type. It's different types. Read OCA.
2. Make variable strong type. Not var but string.
3. Not (!(statement)) but (!statement)